# Create an array of coordinate in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to build an array 'data' like:

```
        series: [{
        data: [[161.2, 51.6], [167.5, 59.0], [159.5, 49.2], [157.0, 63.0], [155.8, 53.6],
            [170.0, 59.0], [159.1, 47.6], [166.0, 69.8], [176.2, 66.8], [160.2, 75.2],
            [172.5, 55.2], [170.9, 54.2], [172.9, 62.5], [153.4, 42.0], [160.0, 50.0]]
        }]
```

with a loop :

```
var listData='';
$.each(jsonUpdate, function (i, item) {
        listData += '[' + i + ',' + item['number'] +'],';
});
```

so i want this:

```
series: [{
        data: listData
        }]
```

My solution doesn't work, how can i do?

Comment: Can you show how your listdata shud look like?

Comment: listData should look like `[[161.2, 51.6], [167.5, 59.0], [159.5, 49.2], [157.0, 63.0], [155.8, 53.6],
            [170.0, 59.0], [159.1, 47.6], [166.0, 69.8], [176.2, 66.8], [160.2, 75.2],
            [172.5, 55.2], [170.9, 54.2], [172.9, 62.5], [153.4, 42.0], [160.0, 50.0]]`

Comment: I don't get it, isnt it the same array?

Comment: No, this is an example,  i want to replace this values with my own value from a json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not handle the array as a string. Use directly [JavaScript arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) :

```
var listData=[];
$.each(jsonUpdate, function (i, item) {
    listData.push([i, item['number']]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not sure what are you up to, however as you stated in comments that you want `listData` to contain the array of `data`. You don't have to use a loop for that.

```
var listData = series[0].data;
```